# docker compose Logstash - specify config file and install plugin?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, logstash

Im trying to copy my Logstash config and install a plugin at the same time. Ive tried multiple methods thus far with no avail, Logstash exists with errors every time

this fails:

```
logstash:  
  image: logstash:latest
  command: logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf 
  command: bash -c bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-translate
```

this fails:

```
command: logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf bash -c bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-translate
```

this fails:

```
command: logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf && bash -c bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-translate
```

this also fails

```
command: bash -c logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf && bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-translate
```

Im having no luck here and I bet the answer is simple... can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: which image your are using?

Comment: image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:6.0.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use the image that I am having locally with the below config, then it's working fine. Hope it helps.

```
version: '3'
services:
  logstash:  
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:5.6.3
    command: bash -c "logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf && bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-translate"
```

Sample output

```
logstash_1  | [2017-12-06T15:27:29,120][WARN ][logstash.agent           ] stopping pipeline {:id=>".monitoring-logstash"}
logstash_1  | Validating logstash-filter-translate
logstash_1  | Installing logstash-filter-translate
```

Comment: this worked when I got a version from the new official elastic repo

Comment: why not install the plugin then call the agent? That was the only clean way it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

try this if it's Ubuntu image

command: bash -c "logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf && bin/- install logstash-filter-translate".
Else it's Alpine image then use

command : sh  -c " command to run "